# Implementing Driver Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, driver, implementation

This may seem like a dumb question but I cannot seem to find an answer anywhere. I ran into this Gem and it is asking to implement a driver. How would one go abouts doing that? Here is the git link

https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system

Again sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You copy-paste the [driver scaffold](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system#usage) provided by the gem author somewhere into your project’s tree and implement all the empty functions needed by the gem to *actually* know about your game of choice.

The easiest way would be to take a [test driver](https://github.com/ozfortress/tournament-system/blob/master/spec/support/test_driver.rb) implemented by the gem author for tests for inspiration.

Comment: Ok so I can copy and paste it anywhere? Or does it need to go into a specific folder?

Comment: Chech the example I linked. Anywhere.

Comment: Ok I am still a little confused. I added the the driver scaffold provided by the author in the controller folder since you mentioned I could put it anywhere. But when it comes to the test driver where do i put that and than how do i call it?